# Why is this function being called every time I try to get its value?

Tags: haskell, recursion, pi

I have this Haskell code that I wrote to calculate pi using the series `π/4 = 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9...`:

```
quarterPi total n s = if (n /= total) then s / (2 * n - 1) + quarterPi total (n + 1) (-s) else s / (2 * n - 1)

calcPi n = 4 * quarterPi n 1 1
```

I ran the code using the GHCi prelude and tried to store an approximation of pi in a variable; something like: `*Main> pi = calcPi 666666`, which would obviously take many many recursive iterations before finishing the calculation. I understand that the first time I retrieve the value of `pi`, it will take time to calculate because of lazy evaluation. For some reason though, it always takes a long time; no matter how many times I use the value or output the value on the screen, it takes several seconds to produce a result. Shouldn't it only have to calculate once because of lazy evaluation?

Comment: A function result is generally recomputed at every function call -- GHC might optimize this so to avoid recomputation, but does not to. Indeed, to always avoid recomputation, GHC would need to cache all the results of all the functions that have been called in the past. That would make garbage collecting anything impossible, since that cache would keep anything alive. Worse, the cache would steadily increase during the program execution, severely impacting performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's biting you here is what's known as the monomorphism restriction – but unusually, it's the *lack* of the monomorphism restriction, rather than its presence.  It turns out `pi` isn't quite as constant as you expected, because its type is more general than you may have realized.

---

If we turn on profiling information at the REPL:

```
*Main> :set +s
```

Then we can see that `pi` is recomputed every time, like you said.

```
*Main> pi = calcPi 666666
(0.00 secs, 0 bytes)
*Main> pi
3.141591153588293
(0.94 secs, 551,350,552 bytes)
*Main> pi
3.141591153588293
(0.99 secs, 551,300,808 bytes)
```

This is because the *type* of `pi` is inferred to be type class polymorphic:

```
*Main> :t pi
pi :: (Fractional a, Eq a) => a
```

So `pi` is in a certain sense "not really a constant"; there are lots of `pi`s!  There's `pi :: Double`, there's `pi :: Float`, there's `pi :: Complex Double`, and so on.  And GHC doesn't cache function applications, so `pi` is recomputed every time.

In Haskell *files*, however, the monomorphism restriction is in effect: a variable binding, like `x = …`, is never inferred to have a type class polymorphic type like `C a => …`.  Such definitions are *defaulted*, if possible – a process where Haskell makes values polymorphic in standard numeric type classes monomorphic at `Integer` or `Double`.  This is why you can write `x^2` without getting an "ambiguous type variable" error (even though the type of the exponent doesn't influence the type of the output); the `2` is silently inferred to be of type `Integer`.

But the monomorphism restriction only applies inside files.  In GHCi, it's disabled.  If we turn the monomorphism restriction back on:

```
*Main> :set -XMonomorphismRestriction
```

Then we can define `pi'`, which we'll only need to calculate once.

```
*Main> pi' = calcPi 666666
(0.00 secs, 0 bytes)
*Main> pi'
3.141591153588293
(0.87 secs, 551,303,896 bytes)
*Main> pi'
3.141591153588293
(0.00 secs, 315,168 bytes)
```

And that's because `pi'` really is a constant.

```
*Main> :t pi'
pi' :: Double
```

---

An additional few notes:

1. Laziness doesn't have to do with why calculating `pi'` is fast the second time; this would be true in a strict language too.  Laziness is why the lines where we define `pi`/`pi'` report "(0.00 secs, 0 bytes)".
2. It's not clear to me if you thought it might, but Haskell will *never* cache the recursive calls you're making.  Something like `calcPi 666666` will always make all 666,666 recursive calls.  It's only once you save it explicitly in a variable that you stop recomputation.
3. The monomorphism restriction and type defaulting are explained in technical language in the Haskell 2010 report: [§4.4.5 "The Monomorphism Restriction](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-930004.5.5), and [§4.3.4 "Ambiguous Types, and Defaults for Overloaded Numeric Operations"](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4).  The GHC User's Guide mentions that the monomorphism restriction is disabled in GHCi, and mentions how to re-/dis-enable it: [§9.17.1 "Switching off the dreaded Monomorphism Restriction"](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#switching-off-the-dreaded-monomorphism-restriction)

Answer (score 0):

GHCi doesn't optimize is well enough to figure out it shouldn't re-evaluate it each time you print it. Normal GHC will properly cache the result if you compile with the usual `-O2` flag.

[Try it online](http://rextester.com/WUEJ73364) and compare the total running time to the number of times it prints out "Pi:3.14..."